# Is there a simple function that generates the series; $1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2...$ or $-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions, exponentiation

I'm thinking about this question in the sense that we often have a term $(-1)^n$ for an integer $n$, so that we get a sequence $1,-1,1,-1...$ but I'm trying to find an expression that only gives every 3rd term as positive, thus it would read;
$-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1...$

Alternatively a sequence yielding $1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2...$ could also work, as $n$ could just be substituted by it in $(-1)^n$

Comment: Check [this out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=closed+form+1,+1,+2,+1,+1,+2,+1,+1,+2,+...).

Comment: For $-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,\ldots$ you can use $(-1)^{n^2\bmod 3}$.

Comment: can you use floor function?

Comment: I first started by trying to find a floor-function representation, and came up short.

Comment: Well, f(n) = 1 if $3|n$ and f(n) = -1 if $3 \not \mid n$ is a perfectly legitimate function. For something less "if then" $(-1)^{\lceil (n/3 - \lfloor n/3\rfloor)\rceil}$ but that just point the "if then" burden where no-one sees it.  Still there are better ones.

Comment: I like the $(2n^2 + 2) mod 3$ suggested by WA as per the comment by Eff

Comment: Any periodic sequence has a corresponding function that can be easily found with DFT.

Comment: Why do you need such a function? If for fun, then the answers are good. If for short notation (for whatever reason), then some are not very convenient. If for easy readability, then most answers are horrible.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a duplicate of a previous question.  But searches like this are not easy in math.se

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I find [Creating an alternating sequence of positive and negative numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512063/).

Comment: $\max(1, n \bmod 3)$

Comment: Couldn't we express the function as; **method 1** referencing the numbers in the sequence: N1 = -1 , N2 = -1, N3 = N1 * N2, N4 = N2 * N3... Or perhaps **method 2** referencing the turn in the sequence: -1*(-1)^(n-1).

Comment: @JukkaSuomela, that's the best one I've seen, actually.  You should post it as an answer.  (Good lord...18 answers....)

Answer (score 145):

Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci sequence $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,...$ then a possible sequence is $$(-1)^{F_{n+1}}$$

Comment: nice observation!

Comment: I like the specific use of Fibonacci. I think a recursive function might even give the OP a direct route, say starting with $1,-1,...$ and then using product of previous two entries.

Comment: $(-1)^\frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: I think it should be $F_n$ not $F_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Nij This is essentially just writing the sequence $(-1)^{F_{n}}$ using the recursive definition of Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 62):

How about $$a_n=\frac 23\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}3\right)+\frac 43\ $$

Comment: Was wondering for a few minutes now why I did not see how this gets to -1 and why it returns 2 until I re-read the question, in particular the second paragraph. I thought my math was failing me completely...

Comment: @luk2302 That's actually interesting because the first time I read the question I completely missed the first paragraph :P

Answer (score 49):

If you want something purely in terms of elementary operations, you could use the closed form:

$$\frac{2}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \omega^n + \omega^{2n}\right)$$

Where $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is a complex cube root of unity. When $3|n$ we get $\omega^n =\omega^{2n} = 1$. On the other hand, when $n$ is not divisible by $3$, $\omega^n$ and $\omega^{2n}$ will be the two roots of the polynomial:

$$z^2 + z + 1$$

And from Vieta we get $\omega^n + \omega^{2n} = -1$.

Comment: This is not obvious from the form of the expression, but this is the same function (extended to complexes) as @BigbearZzz's.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Indeed it is, nice observation.

Answer (score 39):

$$-1+2\left \lfloor {\frac n 3} \right \rfloor -2\left\lfloor \frac {n-1}3 \right\rfloor $$
, where $n$ starts from $1$.

Comment: Computationally the most efficient function here I think. Nice one.

Comment: @tomsmeding Thanks!

Comment: @tomsmeding I don't think it's computionally efficient, because you need 2 divisions, whereas many of the below solutions need only one modulo operation

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Good point, I mentally skipped the ones using modulo because I thought them "cheating", but of course they're easier for a computer.

Comment: computationally efficient is {1,1,-1}[n % 3]

Answer (score 32):

$a(0) = a(1) = -1$
$a(n) = a(n-1) \times a(n-2)$

Comment: Interestingly, this is equivalent to madmatician's answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1899420/153429).

Answer (score 26):

You can check out [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A177702) which gives you several ways to generate your sequence.

For example:

$$a_n=2-((n+1)^2 \pmod 3)$$

$$a_n=\frac{4}{3} - \frac{\cos(2\pi n/3)}{3} - \frac{\sin(2\pi n/3)}{\sqrt3}$$

Answer (score 16):

You could use a simple trig function whose period is $3$. We can therefore try a function of the form $$f(x)=a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{3}\right)+b$$

Substituting the coordinates $(0,2),(1,1)$ gives the values of $a,b$ and we end up with $$f(x)=\frac 23\cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{3}\right)+\frac 43$$ and this generates the required sequence.

Answer (score 14):

No operators!

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if}~x=0\\
-1 & \text{if}~x=1\\
1 & \text{if}~x=2\\
f(x-3) & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Could also eliminate the last case and make the other two $x = 3k$, $x = 3k + 1$, etc.

Comment: Fine except for f(-1) calling an infinite loop.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard there is no such thing as an infinite loop. OP asked for a sequence and sequences have a beginning (typically 0 or 1). Several of the other answers have the same 'issue'.

Comment: @Wildcard: from $f(2-3)=f(2)$ you deduce that $f(-1)=1$. If you really want to programme it, you have to stop briefly and think.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\omega \neq 1$ be a cubic root of unity. We have that $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$, i.e. $\omega + \omega^2 = -1$. Also, $w^{-1} = \omega^2$ and $\omega^3 = 1$.

Put $a_n = \omega^n + \omega^{-n}$. We get the sequences

\begin{eqnarray*}
a_0 &=& \omega^{0} + \omega^{0} = 2 \\
a_1 &=& \omega^{1} + \omega^{-1} = \omega^{1} + \omega^{2} = -1 \\
a_2 &=& \omega^{2} + \omega^{-2} = \omega^{2} + \omega^{1} = -1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

and then the sequence repeats.

If you put $b_n = \frac{2 a_n -1}{3}$, then you get $1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, \cdots$.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

$$(n\bmod3)^2-3(n\bmod3)+1$$

Answer (score 7):

[Iverson bracket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) makes it easy to say exactly what you mean here:

$a_n = 2\cdot[\text{$n$ is a multiple of $3$}] - 1$

or, shorter but more (probably excessively) confusing:

$a_n = 2[3\mid n] - 1$

Answer (score 4):

$$(-1)^{(n\,\text{mod}\, 3)!}$$

Edit. a simpler solution, without a factorial and starting with $n=2$:

$$(-1)^{(n\,\text{mod}\, 3)+1}$$

Comment: Why exponentiate when $(n\pmod 3)!$ gives an equivalent solution?

Comment: @Nij that's for the sequence 1,1,2,1,1. But I realized that you don't even need the factorial.

Comment: The factorial does matter if used as exponent, but not when used directly, to be clear. 0, 1, 2 gives 1, -1, 1. But 0!, 1!, 2! gives 1, 1, 4. Used as exponents they then return 1, -1, 1 versus -1, -1, 1.

Comment: @Nij $2!=2$, not $4$.

Comment: I knew I was making some mistake there. Fortunately it doesn't change the result!

Answer (score 4):

Yet another one:

$$1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n \bmod 3}{2} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: You might consider specifying the meaning by "mod" in this context. In mathematics, "mod" is almost never a function of two arguments like it is in programming and in this answer; instead, it's an equivalence relation. A common alternative is to make a remainder function, $\text{rem}(n,3)$ which returns remainder of $n$ on division by $3$.

Comment: @6005 This is a genuine usage of the `\bmod` modulo function, which does appear in pure mathematics occasionally. This is not to be confused with the `\pmod` modulo *qualifier* on equivalence, which is the standard way to talk about modular equivalence. There's no need to make a separate notation for this usage. FYI, the binary modulo function is natural once you have floor: $a\bmod b=a-b\lfloor a/b\rfloor$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Well, it's fine if you disagree. I don't see how the unmotivated formula "$a - b \lfloor a / b \rfloor$" is "natural". I have taught discrete math classes and you really have to stress, pedagogically at least, that mod is not a binary function. People write things like $a \text{ mod } b = c$ instead of $a \equiv c \pmod{b}$, which is wrong unless $c$ is actually between $0$ and $b-1$. So it does throw a lot of people off, and in my opinion it's bad notation. I'm sure it does appear in *some* math books, but not in any undergraduate or graduate course I took.

Comment: Binary modulo is the most common use. Half the answers on this page make use of it without hesitation or definition. Outside of a discrete mathematics classroom, $a \bmod b = c$ is meaningful and correct.

Comment: @6005 I only mean that binary mod is within the set of functions generated by the field operations plus $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$, so in a sense having one implies having the other as well. I don't see the expression $a\bmod b=c$ very often, but when I do I would understand it just as you have described - $c$ is the unique number equivalent to $a$ in the range $[0,b)$. Obviously this is quite different from $a\equiv c\pmod b$, but they both have their uses.

Answer (score 3):

This works for positive and negative integers of $x$ and produces a sequence of $1,1,2,1,1,2,...$

$y = 2 - (x^2 \text{ mod } 3)$

Or for the sequence $-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,...$

$y = 1 - 2(x^2 \text{ mod } 3)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal, for $n \ge 1$:

$$1+\left\lfloor \frac{1}{n^{(n \pmod {3})}} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor$$

It will provide the sequence: $\{1,1,2,1,1,2,...\}$

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for the change, I did not know that formatting option!

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma**:fibonacci numbers generates:

$odd-odd-even-odd-odd-even-odd-odd-\dots$

**proof**:

If

$F_i=odd$

$F_{i+1}=odd$

Then we have:

$F_{i+2}=even$

$F_{i+3}=odd$

$F_{i+4}=odd$

then the system reapeates.

It gives the formula:

$(-1)^{F_{n}}$

This gives the closed form:

$$(-1)^{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1})}$$

Which is really ugly.I will introduce Lucas numbers to make this better.

Lucas numbers look like fibonacci numbers but $F_1=1$ and $F_2=3$.

Which gives the same odd and even resault.Then we can write:

$(-1)^{L_n}$

That gives the closed form:

$$(-1)^{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

$$2\times((n+1\bmod3) \bmod 2)-1$$

Answer (score 2):

my 2 cents, how about

$a_{n+1}=(-1)^{r(a_n)(1-a_n)}$
where $a_0 = 1$ and $r \in  \{1,2,3\}$
which is similar to the logistic map
in general I think that using a one dimensional chaotic polynomial could help.